# Need help formatting a table properly with images and columns

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

In my app I have a view who's task is to display items and prices related to this item.

Here's how my view renders the table results:

```
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Object Name", "BrowseObjectList", new { _sortOrder = ViewBag.CardNameSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                Object Image
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Object Provider Name", "BrowseObjectList", new { _sortOrder = ViewBag.ObjectProviderNameSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Highest Price", "BrowseObjectList", new { _sortOrder = ViewBag.HighestPriceSortParm })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Price Date", "BrowseObjectList", new { _sortOrder = ViewBag.PriceDateSortParm })
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            var className = i%2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";
            <tr class="@className">
                <th rowspan="5">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Model[i].m_Obj.m_ObjName, "ObjectPriceLists", new { id = Model[i].m_Obj.m_ID}, new {@class = "NavLink" })
                </th>
                <th rowspan="5">
                    @Html.Image(Model[i].m_Obj.m_ObjImageLink, Model[i].m_Obj.m_ObjName, null)
                </th>
                @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].m_ItemPriceLists.Count; j++)
                {
                    <tr class="@className">
                        <td style="height: 100%">@Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].m_ItemPriceLists[j].m_Provider.m_ProviderName)</td>
                        <td style="height: 100%">@Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].m_ItemPriceLists[j].m_PriceHigh)</td>
                        <td style="height: 100%">@Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].m_ItemPriceLists[j].m_PriceListDate)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Right now, it renders "Ok" as the view shapes up to what I wanted, something like this:

```
Object Name Object Image    Provider    Highest Price   Price Date
                            Prov 1                 1    2013-05-03
                            Prov 2                 2    2013-05-03
Object 1    Image           Prov 3                 3    2013-05-03
                            Prov 4                 4    2013-05-03
```

Now that's the WANTED result. The "Object Name" column is a single column, like in an excel page, and the image is a single column as well. Each of the "providers / highest price / price date" is a single line on the **same row** as the object name and image. However what I have is something shaped like this:

```
Object Name Object Image    Provider    Highest Price   Price Date
                            Prov 1            1         2013-05-03
                            Prov 2            2         2013-05-03
                            Prov 3            3         2013-05-03


Object 1    Image           Prov 4            4         2013-05-03
```

What you need to see here is that the 4th provider line resizes in height to match the scale of the image and object. The "Object 1" column and the "Image" takes the height of the image, but the height is not divided evenly between each four providers. Only the 4th resizes to fill the remaining spaces.

Now I know my html layout may be crappy since I'm beginning in html formatting, and I'd like to know how to shape this correctly so that every lines are evenly sized.

**Edit**

My case is hard to describe, but here's an excel demonstration of what I want and what I got:

[image: Problem example using excel]

Comment: Maybe you have some blank data in your database, so its actually looking right, its just inserting 2 extra rows that hold no data. Debug, and before you model bind, look at what the collection actually holds. You also don't need to specify the height of each cell in your table.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out and tell you what I find out.

Comment: If you look at how you render your html, you are rendering <tr>'s inside <tr>'s. Move the last </tr> up, just above the line with `@for (int j `

Comment: oh @MajorByte is right, I didn't notice that. More than likely **that** is your issue

Comment: Yeah, I thought so... but up to now that's the closest to what I actually want to be rendered. That's why I'm using <tr> inside <tr>

Comment: @MajorByte Ok, I will try it.

Comment: Well if I put the last<tr> tag outside of the @for loop, all the <td> inside the loops lines up instead of stacking like before. So I end up having Prov 1 1 <date> Prov 2 2 <date> one after the other instead of one over the other like before.

Comment: No. What I want is a single row, from Object 1, with a single image, but all four providers and dates aligned, like in a excel window.

Comment: @MajorByte I have made an excel image that shows what I intended to do and what I have got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might need some tweaking from your side, but I'd image something like this should do it:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        var className = i%2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";
        @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].m_ItemPriceLists.Count; j++)
        {
            <tr class="@className" style="height:38px;">
            @if(j == 0) {
                <td rowspan="4">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Model[i].m_Obj.m_ObjName, "ObjectPriceLists", new { id = Model[i].m_Obj.m_ID}, new {@class = "NavLink" })
                </td>
                <td rowspan="4">
                    @Html.Image(Model[i].m_Obj.m_ObjImageLink, Model[i].m_Obj.m_ObjName, null)
                </td>
            } else {
                <td></td>
            }
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].m_ItemPriceLists[j].m_Provider.m_ProviderName)</td>
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].m_ItemPriceLists[j].m_PriceHigh)</td>
                <td> @Html.DisplayFor(item => item[i].m_ItemPriceLists[j].m_PriceListDate)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

Dtyle your rows with a fixed height in pixels, being image height/rowspan.. http://jsfiddle.net/vUKfX/2/

Comment: Yep, fixed height, 150 px high.

Comment: and a fixed number of rows?

Comment: Well, you see the structure up above. The only thing that will change is the Model.Count; depending on the result, it might be 1, or 245 items, or more.

Comment: @HerveS I've updated the answer with code that would more or less do what you'd like it to do ...

Comment: You know what? I had to remove the `else` part because it made everything wrong. But other than that, it works PER-FECT-LY. Nice! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the reason for this issue is because your Image is longer than the height of the four data rows combined, and you want the rows to scale equally.

You have several options. You could simply change the rowspan="5" to rowspan="6" for the Image cell, this will allow it to drop a row without scaling the bottom data row. But that's probably ugly.

Here's a better looking solution, gets what you want, but it's ugly code (border added for visualization):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>Object Name
    </th>
    <th>Object Image
    </th>
    <th>Object Provider Name
    </th>
    <th>Highest Price
    </th>
    <th>Price Date
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <table border="1">
      <tr>
       <td>Object 1
       </td>

       <td>Object 1 Image<br />
        Object 1 Image<br />
        Object 1 Image<br />
        Object 1 Image<br />
        Object 1 Image<br />
        Object 1 Image<br />
        Object 1 Image<br />
        Object 1 Image<br />
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
     <table border="1" width="100%">
      <tr>
       <td>asdf</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>asdf</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>asdf</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

       <td>asdf</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
       <td>qwer</td>
      </tr>
     </table>

    </td>
   </tr>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But probably the best solution is to adjust your image height...

Hope that helps!